# How do you open multiple markdown previews at the same time in VS Code?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, [as you can see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_dynamic-previews-and-preview-locking), opening a md file in preview mode will replace a current preview instead of adding another preview. You can only ever have one markdown preview open at a time.

How can I instead get the alternative behavior, where opening a md file in preview mode adds a brand new preview tab no matter what?

Answer (score 19):

While this isn't a perfect solution to the question, this is in my opinion a good workaround to this unwanted behavior.

1. In VS Code, open a markdown file in the normal editor (not preview) mode.
2. While currently on that markdown tab, open the Command Palette using your typical shortcut (on macOS the shortcut is `cmd+shift+p`).
3. Now you need to search for the command 'Markdown: Open Locked Preview to the Side'. You can easily find it by typing 'locked'.
4. So that you get rid of the side-by-side view, then drag that locked preview from the right side into your original left side. Now you have a locked preview that won't get replaced, ever. Do this for every markdown file you open. A little tedious but it works. Yay!

Another way to do this is to open a markdown file in preview mode. And then go to Command Palette & then search for and run 'Markdown: Toggle Preview Locking'.

Comment: Thanks, this at least somewhat works though it's not easy to change the previews once locked.

Comment: Excellent answer! TA

Comment: Just learned about Locked Preview! Thanks for this.